# Having huge problems importing rig and animations into Unity

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes, unity

I've been trying for a while now to set up a first person rig with a rifle and import it into Unity. It just wont seem to work, ive been trying for days and I've had so many problems, sometimes the weapon just floats there and sometimes it just doesnt move the same way it does in blender.

So my question is, are there any good tutorials or easier ways of doing this cause blender and unity seem to just not agree with each other?